# What happened to being able to "protect" a question?

Tags: support

I noticed [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/138056/4512) question was getting too many "me too", and in one case offensive, posts, so I was going to "protect" it.  I know I have done this before.  It requires anyone answering it to have some basic minimum rep.  The bar is quite low, just intended to keep very new or drive-by users from chiming in with presumably no additional useful content.

However, the *protect* link is missing.  I can see *share*, *edit*, *close*, and *flag*, but no *protect* as I'm sure I've seen (and used) in the past.

What am I missing?

Comment: I think only moderators can protect a question now. Just raise a flag if you think it needs to be done. But with a question that's only one day old, it's probably better to deal with the answers individually as they come, at least for now.

Comment: @Dave: So this changed at some time? At some point SE decided ordinary users couldn't be trusted to protect questions anymore?  Personally I only did this rarely, although age of the question is not something I used as a criterion.  For me, the question needed to have enough answers, those answers needed to start getting redundant, and it's the type of topic that attracts wannabes to chime in, although without likely adding anything new and useful.

Comment: My mistake. You *can* protect questions, but only after a full day has elapsed. See the [blog post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question) for details. I think you just jumped the gun on this one.

Comment: @Dave: You should make that a answer so I can accept it and this question will be marked as answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Non-moderator users with more that 15K rep can protect questions, but only after a full day has elapsed. See the [blog post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question) for details. I think you just jumped the gun on this one.